# vuex payload is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuex

[image]i am trying to load all invoices in the database together with customers information,but when my app loads i get payload undefined in chrome vue extension. my goal is to display **customer name** instead of the **customer id** in the invoice table. i have alreay declared the relationship between the invoice and customer.

this is the code in my InvoiceController

```
  public function loadInvoice()
{
    
    $results = Invoice::with(['customer'])
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(15);

    return response()
        ->json(['results' => $results]);   
}
```

This is my vuex function to retrieve all invoice from database

```
    const actions = {
      async fetchInvoices({commit}) {
      let response = await Api().get('/invoices/loadInvoice');    
      console.log(response);         
      commit('SET_INVOICE',response.data.invoices)
   },
```

This is my setter and getter

```
   const mutations = {
     SET_INVOICE(state,invoices) {
     state.invoices = invoices
    }
  }
```

This is my customer model

```
  class Customer extends Model
  {
   protected $table = 'customers';

   protected $fillable = ['firstname','lastname','phone','shop_name','shop_addresss'];

   protected $appends = ['text'];

  public function getTextAttribute()
  {
    return $this->attributes['firstname']. ' - '.$this->attributes['lastname'];
  }
```

}

[image]

when i console.log(response) from my fetchInvoice action

Comment: Looks like `loadInvoice()` returns a json object with a `results` key, but your `fetchInvoices` function expects a `invoices` key? Shouldn't it be `response.data.results`?

Comment: @EricGuan i have object array but i still get payload is undefined

Comment: What do you see when you do `console.log(response)`?

Comment: @Terry an object ->data->invoices in that other. i have posted a picture above for console.log(response)

Answer (score 1):

After executing console.log(response) i went through the object hierarchy and realize i have to append .data

```
  async fetchInvoices({commit}) {
    let response = await Api().get('/invoices/loadInvoice');    
    console.log(response);         
    commit('SET_INVOICE',response.data.invoices.data)
},
```